# In Monotouch, how do I change the detail view controller based on row selection

Tags: xamarin.ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I am using the UISplitViewController in my app with the expectation of changing the detail view to different views when the navigation's table view rows are selected.  The problem is that I cannot seem to figure out how to do this.  Even though I set the ViewControllers[1] to the controller that I want to use, nothing happens.  On the apple dev site, the list a sample that uses a SubsitutableUIViewController, but I cannot seem to find that on the monotouch stack.

Advice?

Answer (score 0):

In MonoTouch, to do this call SetViewControllers on the UISplitViewController.  The first index should be the Master view and second the Detail view.

Settings ViewControllers[x] doesn't update the UI.  There is no event internally that would tell the UI to update, this is why they provide the SetViewControllers method.

Another option is to use a UINavigationController in your Detail view, this would give you a back button at the top which might be nice depending on your scenario.

Comment: That makes sense.  I thought there would have been a method to update it once the controller is updated, but I guess they are doing that in the setter.  I will give it a shot later, and mark your answer.  Thanks alot!

Comment: I have just come across this question and I'm having the same difficulty.  However I can't see the method SetViewControllers?  It's not in intellisense or anything?  I'm using MonoTouch 5.2.12.  Has it been removed?

Comment: Just use the `ViewControllers` property and set it with a new array.  This might have been removed at some point, b/c it is better as a property in C#. There is a `SetViewControllers` method on `UINavigationController`, but it allows to set a flag indicating if the new controllers should use a transition animation.  `UISplitController` doesn't have that ability.